# Certificates - What is KSP and CSP

Tags: c#, certificate

In certificates, what is KSP & CSP, and what are their difference?
In C#, how to figure out whether the certificate is using CSP or KSP.

Comment: In what context did you see `KSP`?

Comment: Basically, CSP=Legacy=CryptoAPI and KSP=CNG=CryptoNextGen. Some apps, especially .NET 3.5 and older, don't support KSP/CNG, so then you need a certificate generated with a legacy template that uses a CSP provider for key storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSP is [Cryptographic service provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721572%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_security_cryptographic_service_provider_gly).

KSP is [Key storage provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721590%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_security_key_storage_provider_gly).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx) for samples of working with the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Comment: Can you please explain how KSP is used in certificates? do you have any c# examples?

Comment: Ok, i found this article which helps me understand this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/12/22/invalid-provider-type-specified-error-when-accessing-x509certificate2-privatekey.aspx

Comment: @Suresh Would you care to post a summary of what you learned as an anwer? That link is dead now :(

Answer (score 2):

Use the certutil command.

When generating a certificate request (custom request) in the mmc on Windows Server 2012 R2 for example, you will be presented with a list of choices under the Private Key tab, Cryptographic Service Provider arrow.

For Legacy (CSP), all providers end with Cryptographic Provider.
For CNG (KSP), all providers end with Key Storage Provider.

Example(run cmd.exe as administrator)

certutil "name of the certificate including suffix"
enter password if required
look for the line Provider =